# How to show mobile version like desktop verson on Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I just bought a theme from "themeforest" website and searched all over the internet about how to make mobile version look like desktop version

I saw an example to add this code in my

```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
#shopify-section-1525912530555 .flex-grid__item--50 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
}
```

But it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be impractical to have the mobile version exactly the same as the desktop one? It wouldn't flow well or be easy for users.

I would suggest setting the percentage to 100% so it takes up the entire mobile screen but you might need to use more media queries in order to get all the elements or at least the major one's to match the desktop version :)